# ¿Tiene sentido crear pull request para uno mismo?

Tags: git

Estoy creando ***pull request*** que yo mismo apruebo y mergeo. Al final quedan registrados y pueden ser consultados en el repositorio remoto, pero no se si tiene mucho sentido hacer esto o hay un mecanismo mejor, como pueda ser el uso de etiquetas.

Los uso por costumbre y por facilidad, en proyectos personales y no se si realmente son útiles o es trabajo que está de más.

> Editado

Trabajando en *BitBucket*... que cada plataforma implementa los *pull-request* a su modo.

- Se pueden crear sin asignar a una persona para su revisión, que puede hacer uno mismo.
- Los pull-request tienen título (y descripción), así permiten agrupar
  conjuntos de commits, pudiendo echar un vistazo rápido.
- Los mensajes guardados son una forma de almacenar de forma "resumida"
  el historial de trabajo, como un 'changelog'. Por ejemplo,
  puedes tener 800 commits y 20 *pull-request*.

Comment: ¿Estas haciendo `git pull` para bajar tu código y al momento de hacer `push` estas haciendo un `merge`? ¿es eso o entendí mal?

Comment: @vcasas no creo pull-request en el repositorio remoto, es un mecanismo que se usa para trabajar con repos Git, pero no es parte de Git. Es una opción disponible en sitios donde se almacena el código (bitbucket, github, ...).

Comment: es doble validacion a ti mismo ,  generalmente cuando trabajamos para no perder cambios hacemos un git add . y se suele ir codigo que no debe estar en el commit , al tu hacer el pull-request puedes chequear con calma, por que alli estas casi seguro que esa actualizacion ira a los servidores de produccion

Comment: de igual forma creo que tu pregunta se basa en opiniones , debes cambiarla y ser mas especifico aunque entiendo tu punto de vista

Comment: @Orici En ese caso estaría demás hacer pull request, ya que por lo que comentas el código lo estas trabajando tu solo.

Comment: podemos discutir 15 horas sobre esto

Answer (score 7):

Según la documentación de Github:

> Pull requests let you tell others about changes you've pushed to a
>   repository on GitHub. Once a pull request is opened, you can discuss
>   and review the potential changes with collaborators and add follow-up
>   commits before the changes are merged into the repository.

Básicamente viene a decir que las *pull requests* te permiten informar a otras personas de los cambios que has hecho en un repositorio y, una vez abierta, discutir con las personas que colaboran en el repositorio acerca de los cambios que se van a incluir. Además de discutir acerca de los *commits* concretos **antes** de incluírlos en el repositorio.

Si trabajas tú solo se pierde un poco el sentido de las *pull requests* ya que no hay discusión posible. En cualquier caso, en un repositorio en el que trabajes tú solo tendría sentido usar *pull requests* en el caso de que otra persona quiera añadir alguna corrección a tu código, pero ahí ya entra esa componente *social* que va intrínsica a las *pull requests* por definición.

Si trabajas solo, como digo, tiene más sentido hacer *commits* de manera normal, separando funcionalidad en ramas o como más te guste a ti. La idea de las herramientas es facilitar el trabajo a las personas, si por usar la herramienta estás trabajando más de la cuenta, algo va mal :)

**EDITO**

Acorde al comentario de fedorqui, hay otro caso en el que pueden (y suelen) usar *pull requests* en un repositorio en el que trabajas tú solo. Este caso es, como comenta él, cuando un usuario reporta un error o un problema con el código. En este caso se puede solucionar el error y hacer una *pull request* haciendo referencia esa *issue*, para dejar la trazabilidad de la solución.

Comment: Buena respuesta. Quisiera añadir un caso que he visto en repos abiertos: una persona trabaja en un proyecto abierto, un usuario le reporta un error y entonces crea un pull-request enlazado a ese issue, para que todo quede mejor documentado.

Answer (score -2):

No tiene sentido. Un pull request es para que lo revisen y aprueben los compañeros/ superiores.
Si trabajas solo, commits para llevar control de cambios y merges y ya esta